# PHP further security on anti-CSRF token

Tags: php, csrf

I am learning about how to prevent CSRF using anti-CSRF tokens. Essentially, the idea is to:-

1) generate a token eg Md5 or Sha1 then store this value in a session variable:-

```
$token = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE));
$_SESSION['token'] = $token;
```

2) All forms include this token value in a POST hidden field

```
<input type='hidden' name='token' value='$nonce_token' />
```

Eg what it would look like to user in source code:-

```
<input type='hidden' name='token' value='9ee66e4e63a06ee4b83a3edde4ecd587' />
```

3) Once form sent check POST hidden field token value matches token stored in session value

```
if($_POST['token']==$_SESSION['token']){...ok...}
```

However, this process seems a little flawed since by including the token value in a hidden POST field an attack can simply just look at the website source code to see the token and then just include this in a malicious generated POST form which my application would thus succeed once received as token value sent would match the token value in my session variable, since I essentially show the token value in my hidden field to the attacker.

Thus, my question is what is the best way around this, as a few ideas I had still seem little flawed:-

1) Using _GET instead but this still has flaws like _POST

2) Changing the token value after x minutes or each request but causes usability issues when going back in browser or fail when user filling in form and token value would become outdated compared to updated session token value as  hidden token value would not have updated whilst user filling in a form.

3) Try encrypting hidden POST form token value then decrypting on sending POST but encrypting/decrypting an already hashed value seems complicated especially one way encrypted has values like MD5 etc?

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, this process seems a little flawed since by including the token value in a hidden POST field an attack can simply just look at the website source code

No they can't.

Alice runs a website. Bob visits the website. Mallory is attacking Bob's account.

Bob gets a nonce token when he visits Alice's website.

If Mallory visited the site, Mallory would get a *different* nonce (because Mallory would have a different session).

If Mallory generated a form with malicious data in it (on her website) and tricked Bob into submitting it, then the nonce Mallory put in the form would not match the nonce in Bob's session and the submission would be rejected.

Comment: Never thought of it that way Quentin! So since Mallory would have a different token to Bob, and the more complex I make the token shown in the hidden field (i.e. add Sha1 instead + salt) nearly makes it impossible for Mallory to even think about guessing the token of bobs session. Thanks very much

Comment: John made an [interesting comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18238614/unique-form-token-disables-multitasking-for-the-user/18239028?noredirect=1#comment26741800_18238614) : So what if Mallory embeds Alice's website on her own evil website, say via hidden iframe, Mallory could read the token via jQuery, and use it on the evil form. The server sided token will match the one on the evil form, because embedding the site made a server request...

Comment: @olli — "Mallory could read the token via jQuery" — No, she couldn't. Standard cross domain security features in browsers makes that impossible.

Comment: That's what I almost thought... Thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 3):

What you need to do is make the hidden field the MD5 or SHA1 hash of the session ID with a salt. That way you compare the submitted value with the hash of the session ID plus salt and if they match it is valid. If an attacker can guess the token then they have already stolen the session id and would be pointless to do anymore protecting since login has already been hijacked. It's really as simple as that. Here is some great info per OWASP on how to prevent CSRF https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: Thanks, what your saying is the more complex I make the token shown in the hidden field (i.e. add Sha1 instead + salt) nearly makes it impossible for an attacker to even think about guessing the token of a logged in user, since every user has a different session token generated but if the algorithm generating the token is rubbish makes it easier for an attacker to guess?

Comment: So, Cryptic what you mean is something like the following when generating the hidden form token value - $token=sha1($session_id.$salt); ?

Comment: Yes!, insert that value in hidden field. Compare the submitted field value on server with the same value generated above and if its the same the form was submitted by your user on your server. If an attacker can create another form with the same token it means they have stolen the session id (cookie) and even worse the salt (then you have way bigger security issues at hand). If they have the cookie they can login as the user anyway. The session id will stay the same so you don't need to store the token if you don't want to since it will still generate to the same value for that session id.

Comment: Btw you don't need to make the salt change either, just make it long enough and store it as a constant. If someone can guess what salt you have from a hashed session id then security across the world will fall apart as we know it =oP People try to over complicate CSRF protection, when it just boils down to the simple point of preventing someone from using a fake form/request to have an unsuspecting user submit it using their session. The above example will fix that and it the simplest method to prevent it. Keep in mind always POST forms so your token is never exposed in logs, or urls.

Comment: Thanks Cryptic, really good info, I would give you best answer but have to give it to Quentin , his answer was first and cleared my initial misconception but your answer also helped further my understanding, Thanks much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Let's review the attack scenario:

1. You have a server at `example.com` and you use CSRF tokens in your forms.
2. Each CSRF token is unique, specific to a user and only valid for some time.
3. A malicious third party, Eve, tricks one of your users, Alice, to come to her site, attempting to mount a CSRF attack.
4. If Eve simply tricks Alice into submitting a form to your server without CSRF token, your server will reject it.
5. If Eve also has an account on your server and tries to get *any* token to submit with the form, this will fail because the token is not valid for Alice.

This leaves this scenario: Using Javascript, Eve fetches a form from your server *as Alice*, then submits this form back, including a valid token. I.e. Eve completely impersonates Alice for the entire process of a regular form submission using Javascript. This is prevented by the [Same Origin Policy](http://www.w3.org/Security/wiki/Same_Origin_Policy). Eve's Javascript won't be able to fetch information from your server, Alice's browser will prevent this as it violates the Same Origin Policy.

That is, assuming there are no security holes in the browser which allow Eve to circumvent that policy. This also means that you need to guard against XSS, i.e. against Eve being able to inject one of her scripts into your website, so regular visitors to your site will run Eve's scripts as part of your site, from the same origin.

---

As a bit of self-promotion, I've just implemented a signature based CSRF token library, which you may want to look at: [Kunststube\CSRFP](https://github.com/deceze/Kunststube-CSRFP). I'd also like to solicit peer review and criticism of it, while I'm at it.

Comment: Thanks deceze, that is a good a answer, will also try looking into that script you provided.

Answer (score 1):

At first, you have to keep in mind, that you cannot prevent hackers from attacking  your application, only you can make things harder.

The idea is come clearly when you thinking about what is the main goal of CSRF attacks, The CSRF is an attack that tricks the victim into loading a page that contains a malicious request. It is malicious in the sense that it inherits the identity and privileges of the victim to perform an undesired function on the victim's behalf, like change the victim's e-mail address, home address, or password, or purchase something. CSRF attacks generally target functions that cause a state change on the server but can also be used to access sensitive data.

So as above, attackers don't make attack directly to your web page, they need bridge, that's it they need a Victim, so they can use victim identity and privileges to execute actions.

when you said:

> However, this process seems a little flawed since by including the token value in a 
>   hidden POST field an attack can simply just look at the website source code

it's doesn't make sense, because attacker will not attack himself.

i hope this was help full.

Comment: That makes sense Mohammad thanks. Since the token in hidden post field is unique to the logged in session user. So user bob would not have the same session token generated as user Alice? So, for user Alice to hack user Bobs session, Alice would need to guess Bobs token which the more complicated algorithm + salt , the more harder it is for user Alice to guess Bobs token?

Comment: exactly, that's it, now i have suggestions to make things harder, don't add token to URL (check value with $_GET), because the victim may send the URL to attacker by mistake (Like chating, email, etc ), then you have to change that token every time some action executed by user, for example if he just add new post and every thing goes OK, change the token in session to new one. this will make things harder, if we suppose attacker still the token for one time he can do only one action(if he doesn't already still the whole session), and after it the token changed.