# Unique form token disables multitasking for the user

Tags: php, forms, token, csrf, csrf-protection

If I want to protect my site and users from Cross Site Forgery (CSRF) attacks, I can generate a unique token `$token = md5( time() * rand );` on **every page** that has a form. The token is is submitted in a hidden input field `echo '<input type="hidden" name="token" value="'.$token.'">';` and at the same time stored in a session variable `$_SESSION['token'] = $token;`.

I will check if on any submitted form `if($_POST['token'] == $_SESSION['token'])` and proceed accordingly.

**However some users may multitask.** Which is something that I am actually doing right now, while I am posting this.

While composing my post I open different windows / tabs to possibly research information or look at some other questions on stack overflow. Stack overflow lets me submit the form with no problems.

But if I were to do that on my site doing this - meaning browse other pages while still composing a post/form - my `$token` would be regenerated each time I pull up a different page from my website. Making the hidden `input` token on the form I am working on and eventually want to submit *incorrect*, because it wont match the `$_SESSION['token']` variable anymore, which has been regenerated when I visited a different page...

**Any good ideas how to prevent this issue, or any better solutions to stop CSRF in the first place?**

I want to allow my users to multi task AND want to be protected against CSRF...

Comment: I am not sure how a token is going to prevent this at all.

Comment: a unique token should be used to stop CSRF could be used in GET or POST requests

Comment: @RaymondN: Yea, that's exactly what I am doing, right?

Comment: looks to me you store 1 token in your $_SESSION['token'] ?

Comment: @olli How does a token stop a attacker from embedding a request to your 'page with token'  and get the token and make a request anyway?

Comment: Stop Cross Side scripting (XSS) that way he can't embedding something to fetch the token. but XSS could pretty hard to stop completly

Comment: @RaymondN: and then I also submit it via hidden input field as `$_POST['token']`. Additionally I am implementing XSS protection, but AFAIK that a different issue.

Comment: @John: I am sorry, earlier I meant to send you this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13330390/php-further-security-on-anti-csrf-token But you do have a good point... So pretty much an attacker would embed the entire site on their mock site, and then use the token from the embedded site... Will javascript let you do this? I'll continue this in the other thread.

Comment: @John: `How does a token stop a attacker from embedding a request to your 'page with token'` [Quentin says](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13330390/php-further-security-on-anti-csrf-token/13330445?noredirect=1#comment26743197_13330445) Standard cross domain security features in browsers make it not possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had the same problem with what you state because of single CSRF and it gets replaced unless they submit the latest page, but if you use a array w/session it should solve your problem(s). Also you might want to include a captcha, I'd recommend Google's Recaptcha.

```
session_start();
function createToken(){
    $token = sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));
    $_SESSION['Tokens']['Token'][] = $token;
    $_SESSION['Tokens']['Time'][] = time() + (10 * 60); #10 min limit
    #you can omit/change this if you want to not limit or extend time limit
    return $token;
}

function checkToken($token){
    clearTokens();
    foreach($_SESSION['Tokens']['Token'] as $key => $value){
        if($value === $token){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

function clearTokens(){
    foreach($_SESSION['Tokens']['Time'] as $key => $value){
        if($value <= time()){
            unset($_SESSION['Tokens']['Token'][$key], $_SESSION['Tokens']['Time'][$key]);
            #remove last parameter if you aren't using token time limit
        }
    }
}
```

your HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php createToken(); ?>">
```

PHP Token Checker

```
if(isset($_POST['token']) && checkToken($_POST['token'])){
    #valid token
}else{
    #create error message saying that they tried to repost data or session token expired
}
```

Comment: Nice, that's a great idea! Generating multiple tokens, which expire after a while... Thank you for the great tip!!

Comment: @olli to take it a next step you might want to add something like recaptcha.

Comment: I do use recaptcha in some places on my site, usually only where I would want to prevent bruteforce attacks... I couldn't think of a scenario where it would be realistically possible to bruteforce a token to do a CSRF...?

Answer (score 2):

The browser should keep the correct session id even between tabs and windows the session id should be the same. (dangerous assumption should be tested cross browser to be sure)

generate more tokens that should be valid based on session id.

so you could check something like this.

```
$tokenCorrect = false;

foreach($_SESSION['tokens'] as $token) {
  if ($token !== $_POST['token'])
     continue;
  $tokenCorrect = true;
}

if ($tokenCorrect == false) {
   die(); // 
   // Maybe log to database ?? but watch if possible Denial of Service because somebody can write your disk/ shared diskspace full with only making fast requests with a invalid CSRF token
}
```

Comment: Good idea, thank you! Class' implementation is even more advanced, so I chose that as the best answer... And as far as I know the session ID stays the same between browser tabs, because it is generated on the server (I've done a bunch of test before I started programming to understand some basics) and will be used to identify one user.

Comment: true about that the session will be generated on the server but if the client request again without that session_id a new session will be generated on the server. A browser could reject the required session id when a new window is opend  so it needs to be tested but i know that firefox and IE won't cause problems here